# jtable of characters in Java

Tags: java, string, swing, jtable

I want to create a jtable where each cell should be the size of a single character, without any separation between adjacent characters (i.e adjacent columns). There are no borders between columns so the visualization of a sequence of columns is indistinguible of a jLabel. I have tried many things like making the width of a column as small as possible until each cell is displayed as ... meaning there is no space to print the character. So say I want to have 5 consecutive cells to print the name Alice. What I have achieved so far is a table with this aspect

A l i c e

If I make the column width smaller it shows

... ... ... ... ...

And what I want is:

Alice

Thanks!!

Alvaro

Comment: Why use a JTable?  Why not use a JLabel?  You need to explain the reasoning behind what you're trying to accomplish to get help.

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of doing something like this? This will only work for a single row.

What if you have two rows:

Alice
SWITCH

The minimum width of the column will be controlled by the "W" in the second row, which means you will always have extra space around the "l" in Alice.

Why don't you just use a JPanel with a BoxLayout and then add multiple JLabels to the panel?

Anyway, if you feel you still need a JTable then you can check out the [Table Column Adjuster](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/) which attempts to fit the text. The basic code would be:

```
TableColumnAdjuster tca = new TableColumnAdjuster(table, 0);
tca.setColumnHeaderIncluded( false );
tca.adjustColumns();
```

Also, make sure you use `JTable.setIntercellSpacing(...)` to set the Dimension to 0.